# Quadratic Sieve algorithm implementation

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, maple

I have the following code for Quadratic Sieve Algorithm in Maple:

```
  QS := proc(n::posint, (c := 1.2, cutoff := 7))
local st, nfb, svprimes, svplogs, nsvprimes, M, sievearray, polroots,
      kn, b, fb, rels, A, deps;
st := Initialization(n,c,cutoff);
print('Using multiplier : ');
print(st[1]);
print('Using smoothness bound: ');
print(st[3]);
fb := st[6];
print('Size of factor base: ');
print(ArrayNumElems(st[6]));
svprimes := st[7];
svplogs := st[8];
nsvprimes := st[9];
M := st[5];
sievearray := st[11];
polroots := st[10];
print('Sieving interval of length : ');
print(2*M+1);
sieve(svprimes, svplogs, nsvprimes, M, sievearray, polroots);
print('Sieving done, searching for smooth values.. ');
kn := st[2];
b := st[4];
rels := FindRelations[kn, b, M, fb, sievearray];
print(LinearAlgebra:-RowDimension(A));
gc();
print('Solving a matrix of size ');
print(LinearAlgebra:-Dimension(A));
deps := Dependencies(A);
print('Number of linear dependien fopund: ');
print(nops(deps));
print('Factors: ');
FindFactors(n, rels, deps)
and proc:
```

It is giving the following error: Error, "`(`" unexpected. Can someone help me fix this? Also I was wondering if it was possible to convert this code into a Java or C code? I am not asking anyone to do so but wondering if it is possible. I will give it a try myself but if anyone wants, your welcome to. This is a quadratic sieve algorithm for which I am trying to factor over a hundred digit long number with.

Comment: That looks like psuedocode there. And yes, you can translate that to any (Turing complete) language.

Comment: No, its a code in Maple. Ran into a hinge but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
QS := proc(n::posint, (c := 1.2, cutoff := 7))
```

to,

```
QS := proc(n::posint, c := 1.2, cutoff := 7)
```

If you intend the following to be a function call then change,

```
FindRelations[kn, b, M, fb, sievearray];
```

to,

```
FindRelations(kn, b, M, fb, sievearray);
```

Change,

```
and proc:
```

to,

```
end proc:
```

Change all the single right-quotes (uneval quotes, to Maple) to single left-quotes (name quotes) or double quotes inside all those print statements. Even better, use `userinfo` statements.

Trying to invoke `gc()` reliably like that won't necessarily work as you expect.

Comment: By "Change all the single right-quotes (uneval quotes, to Maple) to single left-quotes (name quotes)", do you mean to change ' to ` where ` is right next to number 1 on the keyboard and above the tab button?

Comment: That is what I mean. Also, you call LinearAlgebra commands on local `A` (as if it were a Matrix), but I don't see where `A` previously gets assigned a Matrix as its value.

Comment: Yeah I am getting an error everytime I type in QS(n1); where n1 is an integer. Error is: Error, (in QS) invalid input: ArrayNumElems expects its 1st argument, A, to be of type rtable, but received Initialization(2540587679940794667690340687375550680603346659692067329168497773203605001736492172162186753216639546135203926161393, 1.4, 9)[6]

Comment: I got the code from http://books.google.com/books?id=TJv-kLZFEigC&pg=PA366&lpg=PA366&dq=General+Number+Field+Sieve+maple&source=bl&ots=msFxvPFH2c&sig=s1IAj2Y_f7EHF9n76-E5hOKaf9Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c1t4UoDRIbGvigK3qICIAw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=General%20Number%20Field%20Sieve%20maple&f=false page 362. Although you did help more than enough, if you have a second, can you check out the code for yourself because I really want this program to work but unable to get it to do so.

Comment: Also you have omitted (at least) the line `A:=rels[3];` in your copying of the `QS` procedure. I am wary of typing in all of the earlier routines `sieve` and `Initialization` since the latter in turn calls `MultSelect`... and perhaps there is a rather large amount of code. I hope you understand that you'll need each and all of `Initialization`, `sieve`, `MultSelect`, and whatever those call too.

Comment: Rather than removing the parentheses from the **proc** line, change them to curly braces to make **c** and **cutoff** optional keyword parameters.